# Update a value after an hour when a record is inserted

Tags: mysql, database-design, view

I am doing a booking system for an iPhone app and I want to update the `Status` value to "Completed" after 1 hour.

I initially wanted to check for the `TIMEDIFF` of the current datetime and StartDateTime to get the remaining time, and update the value through the app once the timer is completed instead. But, I am not able to create the timer when the application terminates, so I need to create it in the database instead.

I'm not sure whether this is achievable, can anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Why do you actually need to have a **Status** column in the table?. Just *compute* it's value when needed. If (current_time < start + 1 hour) and (end time is null) => we're in use, otherwise, it's completed. You can have this as a *computed column* in a `VIEW`. Most databases cannot update things in a *deferred* fashion, and most probably for a good reason.

Comment: @joanolo You actually made a very good point. This is my first time modeling a database so I'm not familiar with the standard practices and stuff. Thank you so much!

Comment: @joanolo that (comment) looks like (it could be converted to) an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do: be self-critical with your original data model:

*Why do you actually need to have a **Status** column in the table?*

The status *can* be computed from the `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`. You just have one straightforward alternative: compute its value when needed. If (current_time < start + 1 hour) and (end time is null) => we're in use, otherwise, it's completed. You can have this as a computed column in a VIEW. In MySQL you'd do:

```
CREATE VIEW job_log_with_status AS
SELECT
    ID, ResourceID, StaffID, StartDateTime, EndDateTime,
    TimeDiff(Coalesce(EndDateTime, now()), StartDateTime) AS TimeSpent,
    CASE 
        WHEN EndDateTime IS NOT NULL THEN 'Completed'
        WHEN TimeDiff(now(), StartDateTime) > time '01:00:00' THEN 'Completed'
        ELSE 'In Use'
    END AS status
FROM
    job_log ;
```

(Assumption: your original table is called `job_log`)

When used, this view would output something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM job_log_with_status;
```

```
ID | ResourceID | StaffID | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | TimeSpent | status   
-: | :--------- | :------ | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-------- | :--------
 1 | CM-01      | 175124N | 2017-07-13 18:41:53 | null                | 02:00:00  | Completed
 2 | CM-02      | 175124N | 2017-07-13 20:11:53 | null                | 00:30:00  | In Use   
 3 | CM-01      | 175124N | 2017-07-13 19:26:53 | 2017-07-13 20:26:53 | 01:00:00  | Completed
 4 | CM-02      | 175124N | 2017-07-13 19:56:53 | 2017-07-13 20:06:53 | 00:10:00  | Completed
```

You can check the setup and some sample data at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=55e9a63d79eec95ec3a4f54d3b71b761)*